# AWS Lambda Kinesis consumer - kinesis data json in js

Tags: json, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

using default blueprint from kinesis consumer has the following line

```
// Kinesis data is base64 encoded so decode here
const payload = new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
```

kinesis.data is valid json yet is not accessible as JSON object, probably because it is now a string. What do I use to keep it as JSON?

Newb question, thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can use JSON.parse(payload) for getting JSON object from String.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`const payload = JSON.parse(new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('utf-8'));`